# Android Countdowntimer issue

Tags: android, android-studio, time, countdown, countdowntimer

I have a problem with my countdowntimer.
My app has a textview saying "tap to start" then the countdown starts from 3. My problem is when I set textview visibility(View.GONE) the countdown starts from 2 if I delete the line where i set visibility the countdown works fine (starting from 3) but of course the textview remain visible
I use 750 instead of 1000 in countdown because with 1000 the countdown always starts from 2
why this happen ? How can I solve this ?

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:text="Tap to start"
    android:id="@+id/starttext"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>



public void countdowntostart(){
    TextView timetostart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.starttext);
    timetostart.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3000, 750) {
    TextView timestart = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playtimetext);


    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        timestart.setText("" + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
      abcuu();
    }
}.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView`'s text display 2 is because the system have already calculated one second before it run `onTick()` method, therefore the 3 seconds countdown is still accurate even though the text view was displaying 2 when the countdown started. If you wish to show countdown value on a `TextView`, you can set the initial countdown value into `TextView` before the countdown.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are not giving it a specific rounding. Try `Math.ceil((double) millisecondsUntilFinished / 1000);`

If that doesn't work, you might also try setting your `timerstart` text to "3" when you start the timer. Otherwise, I created a CustomCountdownTimer class that also has abstract methods for onStarted, onPaused, etc.

```
public abstract class CustomCountdownTimer {

    private long millisInFuture;
    private long countDownInterval;

    private int secondsRemaining;

    private boolean started;
    private boolean paused;

    public enum State {
        RUNNING,
        PAUSED,
        STOPPED,
        RESUMED,
        STARTED,
        FINISHED,
        STATUS
    }

    public CustomCountdownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        this.millisInFuture = millisInFuture;
        this.countDownInterval = countDownInterval;

        started = false;
        paused = false;

        initialize();
    }

    public boolean isPaused(){
        return paused && isStarted();
    }

    public boolean isStarted(){
        return started;
    }

    public void pause() {
        paused = true;
        timerPaused(secondsRemaining);
    }

    public void resume(){
        paused = false;
        timerResumed(secondsRemaining);
    }

    public CustomCountdownTimer start() {
        started = true;
        return this;
    }

    public void stop() {
        millisInFuture = 0;
    }

    public void initialize() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Log.v("status", "starting");
        final Runnable counter = new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                long sec = millisInFuture / 1000;

                if(started && !paused) {
                    if(millisInFuture <= 0) {
                        Log.v("status", "done");

                        started = false;
                        onFinish();
                    } else {
                        Log.v("status", Long.toString(sec) + " seconds remain");
                        millisInFuture -= countDownInterval;
                        secondsRemaining = (int) Math.ceil(((double) millisInFuture / 1000));

                        handler.postDelayed(this, countDownInterval);
                        onTick(secondsRemaining);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v("status", Long.toString(sec) + " seconds remain and timer has stopped!");
                    handler.postDelayed(this, countDownInterval);
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(counter, countDownInterval);
    }

    public void updateTimer(long millisInFuture){
        this.millisInFuture = millisInFuture;
    }

    public abstract void onTick(int secondsRemaining);
    public abstract void onFinish();
    public abstract void timerPaused(int secondsRemaining);
    public abstract void timerResumed(int secondsRemaining);

}
```

Use it like this:

```
CustomCountdownTimer customCountdownTimer = new CustomCountdownTimer(totalSeconds * 1000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(int remainingSeconds) {
        // Code on each tick
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // Code to run when finished
    }

    @Override
    public void timerPaused(int remainingSeconds) {
        // Code to run if paused
    }

    @Override
    public void timerResumed(int remainingSeconds) {
        // Code to run when resumed from paused
    }
};

customCountdownTimer.start();
```

Note that this is using full seconds rather than milliseconds, and it will show 3 when you start, rather than 2, because it's rounding up like I suggested earlier.

Comment: And for anyone interested, I went with full seconds rather than milliseconds because it worked for what I was using it for when I created it.